# How to setup mailserver on Windows XP standalone?

Tags: windows-xp, imap, smtp, pop3, mail-server

I'm playing with the javamail API. To test my code about the only thing that seems to work is to connect to my web email (yahoo/msn/gmail/rediff) and do the deed. The trouble with testing online is that I have a bandwidth cap.

My computer is a standalone box. I found a reference to hMailServer here on superuse but it seems to require a database installation too...

Is there a way I may setup a mailserver locally on windows itself? A last option in my mind is to move this application to my virtual-box slackware and run the mailserver there ...

Comment: Is not installing a database server, i.e. SQL Express, a constraint?  I installed hMailServer locally, including SQL Express, and use the database server for many other development tasks.

Comment: addendum:  I remember during setup that hMailServer has a non-database option during custom/advanced setup.  Probably just uses the file system directories.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see. Thanks Robert (+: